# Can't remove or update inline style with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm setting an inline `box-shadow` style on a `div.wrapper` when a user clicks a `#menu-open` link. This overrides a default CSS style that is applied via the stylesheet. That is working.

However I also want to be able to remove that inline style when the user clicks the `#menu-close` link so that we then default back to the style in the CSS file.

I currently have the following;

```
<p id="menu-open">...</p>
<p id="menu-close">...</p>

<div class="wrapper">...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#menu-open').click(function(){
            jQuery('.wrapper').css('box-shadow', '0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)');
        });
        jQuery('#menu-close').click(function(){
            jQuery('.wrapper').css('box-shadow', '');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried `removeAttr('style');` and `attr('style', '');` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
jQuery('#menu-close').click(function(){
    jQuery('.wrapper').removeAttr('style');
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bSNE7/)

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, I've tried `removeAttr` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

from jQuery 1.8+ you can simply use (crossbrowser) without using vendor specific prefixes.try this:

```
  jQuery('.wrapper').css({ boxShadow: '0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)'});
```

for removing it,use:

```
  jQuery('.wrapper').css({ boxShadow: ''});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bSNE7/1/)**

Comment: why are you saying that? The OP hasn't used vendor prefixes.

Comment: because `boxShadow` css property is provided in jquery 1.8.3 that handles all browser prefixes.using `css('box-shadow')` may not work in some browser.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/7haVh/

You need to put your code inside ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#menu-open').click(function(){
    jQuery('.wrapper').css('box-shadow', '0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)');
});
jQuery('#menu-close').click(function(){
    jQuery('.wrapper').css('box-shadow', '');
});
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly fine, exactly as I need, but it's still not removing the style for me even when wrapped in `ready`.

Comment: You have not wrapped your script inside script tag.

Comment: It was wrapped in the correct tags however that wasn't shown, sorry. I've updated the OP to show the full code.